# Why a class property becomes empty?

Tags: php, functions, actions

I have a class with a private property/variable named **$postID** that I can pass successfully (this was tested) to every function within this class except one named **handleForm()**. When it is passed to this function it becomes empty. Why this happens? I suspect that this is because of the `template_redirect` action hook, but I am not sure. The class schematically looks as below. To understand this class better you can look at the original code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210662/25187.

**UPDATE**

For more understanding: I added to a front end posting form the editing functionality, but I want to solve some issues, although [this form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212165/25187) already works.

```
class Post_From_Front {
    ...
    private $postID;

    function __construct() {
        if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && isset( $_POST['postid'] ) ) {
            $this->postID = $_POST['postid'];
        }
        ...
        // Listen for the form submit & process before headers output
        add_action( 'template_redirect',  array( $this, 'handleForm' ) );
    }

    function post_shortcode() {
        ...
    }

    function handleForm() {
        ...
    }

    function getForm() {

        ob_start();
        ?>
           // a form here
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}

new Post_From_Front;
```

The full code can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/iuriemalai/5bad5e05c92b1cec10db

Comment: It might help to see the code in your `handleForm()` function, but I suspect it's because the `template_redirect` action hook doesn't pass any variables.

Comment: @pat-j The `handleForm()` function is a bigger one, but you can look at the original code to understand this class better: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210662/25187

Comment: have you verified that it enters the `if` condition on the requests where `handleForm` is called? what happens if you also add the action inside that `if` condition? does it get successfully added and called?

Comment: @milo I am not sure if I understood you correctly. I moved the `template_redirect` action hook inside the `if` condition but it doesn't get called.

Comment: What does your form look like? If the `if` condition doesn't get called, then the postID will be empty

Comment: @czerspalace I tested with `echo $this->postID` in every function and the `postID` value was outputted, except from the `handleForm()` function.

Comment: You mentioned that when you moved the action hook inside the if condition it didn't get called. Have you echo'ed `$this->postID` from within the if condition?

Comment: @czerspalace Yes, the value of  `$this->postID` was outputted.

Comment: If you add  the `add_action` back in the `if` statement, does it still not get called?

Comment: Where/how is `handleForm()` used?

Comment: @s-ha-dum You can see my full code here: https://gist.github.com/iuriemalai/5bad5e05c92b1cec10db